# How do I parse a field from the route paramMap and return it as an object?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

In my component, I have this function:

```
  getData(): DataObj {
    const data = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('data');
    const obj = JSON.parse(data) as DataObj
    return obj;
  }
```

but the line

```
    const obj = JSON.parse(data) as DataObj
```

gives the compilation error

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

complaining about "data". What's the proper way in strict mode to parse and then return my object?

I'm using Angular 14.

Comment: `data` is `string` **`| null`** and `JSON.parse` wants a `string`. So what _should_ happen if the parameter isn't provided? You either need to explicitly deal with the null case, or tell the compiler you know it's never going to happen with a type assertion.

Comment: I'm interested in a Typescript strict way in dealing with the null case.

Comment: Then decide what should happen in that case and deal with it, that'll inform the compiler too.

Comment: What is the `DataObj` type? This information is missing in your question. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [Type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) should be your friend here.

Deal with `null` earlier, to get type narrowing working.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
  getData(): DataObj {
    const data = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('data');
    if (data === null) return null; // you can return whatever you like
    const obj = JSON.parse(data) as DataObj; // now this line should not complain about `null`
    return obj;
  }
```